# Can I add another outlet to an existing load outlet?

Tags: electrical

I have an existing outlet with four wires plus the ground. I want to add an outlet directly outside the house using the existing outlet as the feed. Can this be done?

Comment: By four wires, do you mean there is one pair of white and black coming in to the box and another pair of wires exiting (both with ground)?

Comment: What country are you in? Different countries will have different regulations

Comment: In US.    Two black wires on the copper side and two white wires on the silver side.

Comment: What room is this outlet located in?

Answer (score 1):

You may need a different outlet but yes it can be done. Back and side outlets have a clamp that will hold 2 wires under each screw or 4 blacks on the hot side then 4 whites on the neutral side. Your limitation may be the size of the box and the wire size these would be needed to calculate the "box fill". Don't forget the outside receptacle will need to be a GFCI or the circuit protected by a GFCI Circuit breaker.

Comment: Do you mean one of the $3 jobs, like [this Leviton commercial grade](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-20-Amp-Commercial-Grade-Duplex-Outlet-White-R62-CBR20-00W/202066702) unit?

Comment: Well that is a 20 amp outlet but it looks close having trouble with internet been on generator  power for 8 days,  will try to verify when I have a good connection tomorrow snowing here hard again , already lost several stalls , hay storage, shaving storage areas, but our arena is still standing, 2 of our friends not as fortunate with collapsed arenas and barns with horses that did not make it,  probably TMI but will try.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, with a few considerations.  The first is that the current box will most likely need to be replaced with a larger one.  There are "box fill calculations" that determine the size of the box to be used based on the number and size of wires in the box.  The most common boxes are fine for 4 wires, but once you jump up to 6, you typically need a bigger box.  The good news is that it's normally easier to do a job like this by removing the existing box inside so you have more room to work.

Connecting all 6 wires in the box can be cumbersome even in the largest single-gang boxes, so I would recommend using what is called a "backwire" or "sidewire" outlet.  These allow attaching up to 4 wires per side because the wire goes straight under a clamp rather than needing to be looped around a screw.  The cost a few dollars more, but make this job very easy.

Finally the outside outlet will need to be GFCI protected.  Some people frown on the idea of placing an actual GFCI outlet outside because of their failure rate when exposed to the elements.  Using a weather proof box cover can help with this, but it could just be a matter of time until it succumbs to the elements.  The other choice is to protect the entire circuit with a GFCI breaker.  The breaker route will cost more, but it will protect all existing outlets on the circuit and won't be exposed to the elements.

Make sure a GFCI breaker is available for your panel and it will fit before getting married to that idea.  Also, you could be tempted to put the GFCI breaker inside and connect the exterior outlet to the LOAD terminals, but putting a large GFCI outlet in a box with 6 wires isn't going to work.  You could perhaps put the GFCI outlet in place of the previous outlet in the "chain", but that's probably more confusing than just using a breaker or putting it outside.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain locations (bathrooms & kitchens, but possibly others) where under some circumstances circuits are supposed to be limited to those locations. But as a *general* rule, you can remove one of the pairs of wires (black & white), add pigtails (short pieces, same colors) to where the original wires were connected, and use wire nuts to connect the old wires, the pigtails to the existing receptacle, and wires to the new receptacle together to power a new receptacle elsewhere.

Keep in mind that new outdoor receptacles are required to have GFCI protection. If the existing circuit is already protected (GFCI circuit breaker, or GFCI receptacle **wired correctly**) then you will be fine. If not, the new receptacle will need to include GFCI protection. But that can cause additional problems because outside GFCI receptacles are prone to damage over time. Better is to either replace the original circuit breaker with a GFCI breaker (usually easy, unless the original circuit breaker is actually an old fuse, or if the original circuit breaker is a 1/2 size (aka double stuff) breaker) or replace an existing receptacle in the circuit with a GFCI receptacle **and wiring the load connections to the new receptacle correctly**.

Outdoor receptacles also need to be weather resistant. "Weather resistant" is no guarantee of prevention of rain & other weather causing problems, but improves the odds.